# How to save R model without dataset in the model saved file

Tags: r

How do I save my fitted model with data used to fit the model?

For example:

```
model_glm <- glm(dlq ~. , data=mydata, family="binomial")
save(file="model_Save_obj", model_glm)
```

The size of model object (`model_glm`) is same size as my dataset size (both are 6MB)?

How can i save only model without data.

Comment: `save(mydata, model_glm, file="model_save.rda")`

Comment: If you read [`help("save")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/save.html), you'll see `...: the names of the objects to be saved`. In general, in R functions that permit zero or more arguments, it uses the `...` syntax. In this case it doesn't make sense to provide zero, per se, but the point is that you can provide one, two, or two hundred just as directly.

Comment: The size of model object (model_glm) is same size as my dataset size (both are 6MB)?

How can i save only model without data.

Comment: You started with *"how to save R model and dataset in one file"*, and now you want to save the model *without* your data. Please be clear on your needs. For data removal, you do that with `model_glm$data <- NULL` and then `save(model_glm, file="...")`, but I don't think it'll save much space: the model (without data) is reduced only 7% (using `mtcars`), largely due to all of other components of the model. If you look at `dput(model_glm)` and go through all its components, you'll see large-ish structures such as `$qr` and `$model` which are important for other model analysis.

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple objects in the same file, just list those objects in the `save` command:

```
save(mydata, model_glm, file="path/file.RData")
```

Model objects can be large (even as large as your data) because they often contain many things. For example, `glm` returns a list that contains vectors of the coefficients, the residuals, the fitted values, and other things.  See `?glm` for a complete list.

Comment: The size of model object (model_glm) is same size as my dataset size (both are 6MB)?

How can i save only model without data.

Comment: is there any model which save in very less size ?

Comment: The function `glm` returns a list that you have saved in `model_glm`.  You can choose to just keep some of that list, for example, by doing `model_glm$coefficients`